# Что почитать для создания воксельного движка?

Tags: c++, opengl

хочу написать свой воксельный движок на c++ и визуализацией через opengl. Вопрос собственно - что почитать чтобы написать воксельный движок.

P.s. opengl я плюс минус знаю, нужна инфа лишь про воксели.

Comment: А кто-нибудь знает что такое "воксель"?

Comment: типа майнкрафта?

Comment: можно банально заглянуть на хабр. там есть немного.

Comment: @KoVadim к сожалению на хабре очень  мало и ничего из этого не понятно.

Comment: @magrif к сожалению или к счастью нет)

Comment: @nick_n_a можно сказать это противопоставление полигонам. Если интересно можете посмотреть супер крутую игрушку teardown.

Comment: Вопрос слишком широк. Начать с того, что под вокселями даже разные вещи понимают (сравните Майнкрафт, Teardown, Outcast 1999 года)